# ValueError: Matrix must be square. For the simulated-bifurication algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, algorithmic-trading

I tried the following code to run the simulated bifurcation algorithm. However, I received an issue during the implementation.

Here is the code:

```
    !pip install yfinance
    !pip install numpy
    !pip install pandas
    !pip install simulated-bifurcation

    import yfinance as yf
    import torch
    import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
    import yfinance as yf
    import numpy as np
    import simulated_bifurcation as sb
    
    
    def get_data(asset_name, period='1y', interval='1d'):
        data = yf.download(tickers=asset_name, period=period, interval=interval)
        return data
    
    
    def optimize_sb(matrix, **kwargs):
        sb.set_env(time_step=.1, pressure_slope=.01, heat_coefficient=.06)
        best_vector, best_value = sb.maximize(matrix, **kwargs)
        return best_vector, best_value
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asset_name = 'AAPL'
    data = get_data(asset_name)
    matrix = torch.tensor(data.to_numpy())

    agents = 100
    max_steps = 10000
    sampling_period = 30
    convergence_threshold = 50
    device = 'cuda' # To enable the GPU

    best_vector, best_value = optimize_sb(matrix, agents=agents, device=device,
                                      max_steps=max_steps, sampling_period=sampling_period, ballistic= True,
                                      convergence_threshold=convergence_threshold, use_window=True, heated=True, best_only=True)
```

Here is the issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  
6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/simulated_bifurcation/polynomial/base_multivariate_polynomial.py in __check_square_matrix(matrix)
    252             raise ValueError(f"Matrix requires two dimension, got {matrix.ndim}.")
    253         if matrix.shape[0] != matrix.shape[1]:
--> 254             raise ValueError("Matrix must be square.")
    255 
    256     def __check_vector_shape(self, vector: torch.Tensor) -> None:

ValueError: Matrix must be square.
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................